# consteval: Call to consteval function 'encrypt_string' is not a constant expression, pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression

Tags: android, c++, c++20, constexpr, consteval

I want to create a simple string encryption in C++ using the consteval keyword. Previously, I used constexpr, which worked, but some strings were encrypted at runtime. So, I decided to switch to consteval, which, as I understand, ensures that the function always runs at compile time.

Now I am getting this error:

```
Call to consteval function 'encrypt_string' is not a constant expression
pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression
```

I am not sure what this mean.

Currently I am using a macro to encrypt the strings, and it is replaced with this code:

```
decrypt_string(encrypt_string((char[]) { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" }, sizeof(char[])
    { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" }),sizeof(char[])
    { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" })
```

`encrypt_string()` is the function declared consteval.

the two functions look like this:

```
consteval auto encrypt_string(char string[], uint32_t len) {
    for (int i = 0; i != len; i++) {
        string[i] = string[i] ^ keys_expr[i & 7];
    }
    return string;
}

__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) __attribute__((noinline)) __attribute__((optnone))
auto decrypt_string(char string[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i != len; i++) {
        string[i] = (string[i] & ~keys[i & 7]) | (~(string[i] & keys[i & 7]) & keys[i & 7]);
        //string[i] = string[i] ^ keys[i & 7];
    }
    return string;
}
```

[image]

I am compiling this in Android Studio so the compiler should be clang.
I added this line to build.gradle

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags '-std=c++20'
    }
}
```

This is the full error:

```
C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android24 --sysroot=C:/Users/*/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -Dapkpath_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++20 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/apkpath.dir/apkpath.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\apkpath.dir\apkpath.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/apkpath.dir/apkpath.cpp.o -c C:/Users/*/AndroidStudioProjects/ApkPath/app/src/main/cpp/apkpath.cpp

C:/Users/*/AndroidStudioProjects/ApkPath/app/src/main/cpp/apkpath.cpp:15:17: error: call to consteval function 'encrypt_string' is not a constant expression
        decrypt_string(encrypt_string((char[]) { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" }, sizeof(char[])
                       ^
C:/Users/*/AndroidStudioProjects/ApkPath/app/src/main/cpp/apkpath.cpp:15:17: note: pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression
C:/Users/*/AndroidStudioProjects/ApkPath/app/src/main/cpp/apkpath.cpp:15:32: note: temporary created here
        decrypt_string(encrypt_string((char[]) { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" }, sizeof(char[])
                                      ^
```

Comment: What's your compiler, compiler version, and the full error message from the compiler command line?

Comment: @alter_igel I have added the full error

Comment: `sizeof(char[])` -- What is this value going to be?  It certainly can't be used anywhere else in C++, such as `std::cout << sizeof(char[]);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is `sizeof (char[]) { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" }`. It's a char[] initialized inline

Comment: `(char[]) { "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" }` is not valid standard C++ to begin with. So I wouldn't expect it to interact with C++ features such as `constexpr` in nice ways. I would recommend compiling with `-pedantic-errors` so you can't use accidentally use C features that are supported only as an extension in C++ mode. In particular this kind of compound literal has major compatibility issues with similar C++ constructs. For example, what do you expect the lifetime of the array to be? You are storing a pointer to it after all.

Comment: [Errors](https://godbolt.org/z/1xGT1xPKG).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `sizeof(char[])` is not being parsed that way. It is parse as `sizeof( (char[]){ "s/x/apkpath/MainActivity" } )` instead, which is a combination of C and C++ grammar supported by e.g. GCC and would give you the length of the string literal (plus null terminator).

Comment: Why not use std::string_view?

Answer (score 2):

> which, as I understand, ensures that the function always runs at compile time

That's not what `consteval` does. `consteval` functions are not allowed to be invoked in places outside of constant evaluation (hence the name). It doesn't *cause* the invocation to be "compile-time"; it simply forbids uses outside of such evaluations.

It's up to you to use your `consteval` function during constant evaluation. Your call to `decrypt_string` is not constant evaluation, so calling `encrypt_string` during that expression will be outside of constant evaluation. Hence the error.

However, the fundamental algorithm you're trying to implement is not itself going to work. Your algorithm modifies the parameter, which is a *string literal*. String literals are explicitly `const` objects in C++, so modifying them is undefined behavior. And at compile-time, undefined behavior is ill-formed (aka: a compile error).

If you want to make this work, your `consteval` function needs to return a *new string*, not modify the given pointer in-situ. This would generally be done via a template (to get the length of the string literal at compile time), returning a fixed-length string.

Comment: I tried using your code but the error is still the same

Comment: What happens if you remove the `char[]` casts?

Comment: @na29: You are trying to overwrite a *string literal*. C++ doesn't let you do that. It's UB at runtime, so it's a compile error at compile-time.

Comment: I am using the string literal to initialize a char[] so I am not overwriting a constant

Comment: @na29 The problem is that this is a compiler-specific extension in GCC and not standard C++. So it is throwing everyone off.

Comment: @user17732522 you are saying that `(char[]) {"string"}` is a compiler extension?

Comment: @na29 In C++ yes, but not in C. And in C it behaves completely different from the similar looking C++ construct `T{"string"}` (without parentheses) where `T` is some type, which is probably why it was never standardized for C++. Without looking at compiler documentation I couldn't tell you how GCC/Clang decide to implement e.g. lifetime and value category of this construct in C++ mode (i.e. according to C rules or the rules for similar C++ constructs).

Comment: @user17732522 But if its an extension that works for my compiler and I am using C++ why it should not work?

Comment: @na29 It probably always had undefined behavior. According to the documentation of GCC at least (and Clang tries to be compatible with it), in C++ mode compound literals are supported as an extension, but have lifetime of C++ temporaries, i.e. after the function call the pointer is dangling. This is in contrast to C mode where the compound literal has lifetime until the end of the block. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html. `consteval` forces the compiler to notify you about this, because a constant expression may not result in a pointer to a temporary.

Comment: @na29 So as I wrote in the question comments, better to disable the extension than misuse it by assuming the same behavior as in either C or as in similar C++ constructs when neither is standardized and thus completely up to the compiler even if the syntax is supported.

Comment: @na29 *But if its an extension that works for my compiler and I am using C++ why it should not work?* --  Maybe it should work and it is a bug in the way the compiler jerry-rigged this extension, who knows?  A similar situation happened a while ago for g++, where variable length arrays (VLA's) didn't work where regular arrays did work, namely STL algorithm functions.  The g++ team eventually fixed the issue, but this is where you don't have a guarantee how an extension is or was supposed to work with C++ constructs.

Comment: @user17732522 but I don't that the problem is (char[]) {} because it worked well when I used constexpr

Comment: @na29: How compiler extensions interact with other C++ features is ultimately up to the compiler. That it might work in some case but not others is again up to the compiler. You could file some kind of bug report on it to GCC, but that's the most you could do.

Comment: @na29 According to the documentation I linked you the lifetime of the `(char[]) {}` array will end, like C++ temporary objects, at the end of the full expression in which it was created. That means that if you store the result of `decrypt_string(encrypt_string(...))`, which is a pointer into that array, in a variable and use it in a later statement, then you are accessing a dangling pointer. It "working" would be coincidental

Comment: @na29  It compiles with `constexpr` because `constexpr` permits the whole thing to be evaluated at runtime as well, in which case the compiler doesn't have to tell you that you are returning a pointer into a temporary object. Doing that disqualifies the expression from being a constant expression, but as long as you do not use the expression in a context that requires a constant expression, that doesn't matter at all. `consteval` on the other hand enforces that a call to the function is a constant expression, or called in a context that requires a constant expression

Comment: @NicolBolas "_It doesn't cause the invocation to be "compile-time"; it simply forbids uses outside of such evaluations._": That's not correct. If the `consteval` function is invoked outside of a manifestly constant-evaluated expression, then the function invocation will be required to be a constant expression and if it is, then it is well-formed. It is not generally ill-formed to use a `consteval` function outside a manifestly constant-evaluated context.